# How to pass HTTP URL to the antMacher

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I tried:

```
http.requestMatcher(new NegatedRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("http://domainnamea.com/**")));
        http.antMatcher("http://domainnamea.com/**");
```

and am getting the error:

```
defaultTarget must start with '/' or with 'http(s)'
```

I have two domain names and need to configure two separate custom authentication provider classes for that.

How an I pass the URL to `antMacher` ?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use:

```
.antMatchers("/register")
Or with multiple:

.antMatchers("/register","/login","/user","/admin")
We also specify individual pages or directories –

.antMatchers("register.html"); // Individual
.antMatchers("/admin/**"); // Directory
```

Comment: yes I know this but my source is configured to to domain  names as domaina.com and domainb.com I need to changed configurations according to the domain name,http://domaina.com and http://domainb.com,can I do it?

Comment: If your domain has authentication, you can use ```http.cors();```

Comment: @A.perera no, you can't do it. If you want to apply different security rules to different domain names, you will have to use a proxy server (for example, Nginx), which will associate one domain name with one context path, and the other with another.